# VLookUp and formatting

Tags: excel, vba, vlookup

I need to return values from the "Yesterday" sheet along with formatting into the "Today" sheet.
I used a code that created a special "Vlookup" function but it can't bring the source formatting into the "Today" sheet.

This code is in Sheet3(Today) object

```
    Dim I As Long
    Dim xKeys As Long
    Dim xDicStr As String
    On Error Resume Next
    Application.ScreenUpdating = False
    Application.CutCopyMode = False
    xKeys = UBound(xDic.Keys)
    If xKeys >= 0 Then
        For I = 0 To UBound(xDic.Keys)
            xDicStr = xDic.Items(I)
            If xDicStr <> "" Then
                Range(xDic.Items(I)).Copy
                Range(xDic.Keys(I)).PasteSpecial xlPasteFormats
            Else
                Range(xDic.Keys(I)).Interior.Color = xlNone
            End If
        Next
        Set xDic = Nothing
    End If
    Application.ScreenUpdating = True
    Application.CutCopyMode = True
End Sub
```

This one is in Module 1.

```
Function LookupKeepFormat(ByRef FndValue, ByRef LookupRng As Range, ByRef xCol As Long)
    Dim xFindCell As Range
    On Error Resume Next
    Application.ScreenUpdating = False
    Set xFindCell = LookupRng.Find(FndValue, , xlValues, xlWhole)
    If xFindCell Is Nothing Then
        LookupKeepFormat = " "
        xDic.Add Application.Caller.Address, " "
    Else
        LookupKeepFormat = xFindCell.Offset(0, xCol - 1).Value
        xDic.Add Application.Caller.Address, xFindCell.Offset(0, xCol - 1).Address
    End If
    Application.ScreenUpdating = True
End Function
```

Then I used formula **=LookupKeepformat(N2,Yesterday!$A$1:$O$1000,14)** in "Today" sheet.
Simply, I need to bring the value and format into the "Today" sheet.

Comment: What's the relationship between these two bits of code?

Comment: To be honest, I don't know. I found some codes on the web, glued them together and prayed to god. lol

Comment: UDFs can't return cell formats.

Comment: Ha ok well a formula won't generally transfer formats so perhaps use `pastespecial` as in the first bit of code.